# Update ListView, ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

I dont know if is coincidence or not, but after updating Visual Studio 2013 with update 5 my listview doesnt update any more. Because i am not any mvvm wpf expert please for help.

App update List every time when USB plug in or out - this happening with help of backgroundworker and eventhandler.

my ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Devices> devicelist { get; protected set; }
void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    fd.FindDevices();
    RefreshList();
}

void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    fd.FindDevices();
    RefreshList();
}

public void RefreshList()
{
    devicelist = new ObservableCollection<Devices>();
    devicelist.Clear();

    foreach (var item in fd.devices)
    {
        devicelist.Add(item);
    }
}
```

So, if device is pluged in or out, method FindDevices start (this loop just asking for information for every device) and at the end I get List of devices with all the informations. The I like to refresh list. "fd.devices" have right number of devices only WPF doesnt refresh.
If have anyone any question, please ask. And please help me with my issue :)

Comment: Also is interesting when I start the app - public ViewModel(), ListView update normally also over fd.FindDevices and RefreshList()

Comment: How do you bind the data to view ? and also, devicelist.Clear(); doesn't make any sense, since you have already created a new list.

Comment: Sorry Ugur, was already removed while I just playing now something ;) but still doesnt work! :)

Comment: Okay, but then what are doing after  adding "devicelist.Add(item); ",  there should be some code like that  "fd.devices.ItemSource = devicelist " or I dont know, could it be a binding problem. How do you bind your data to view

Comment: He must be binding to the `devicelist` property. Show us the XAML of your ListView, so we can see how you're binding it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Raise a Property changed event. This ripples up to the UI element and basically it refreshes what data it has.

Assuming the list is bound to from the UI?

If you don't already have a base view model class it might be worth looking at this:

- http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm

Comment: Since he's using `ObservableCollection`, there's no need for the Property Changed event when calling the **Add** method.